# Infinite intersection with real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I cannot wrap my head around something I did read in a math book. Maybe someone can tell me at which point I went wrong.

**Background**

The author defines the infinite intersection as follows:

> $$\bigcap_{n \in M} A_{n} := \{ x\,|\,x \in A_{n}\:\text{ for all } n \in M \}$$

Later on the author brings up an example:

> $$
> M = \mathbb{N}, A_{n} := \Big\{ x \in \mathbb{R}\, \Big| \,0 < x < \frac{1}{n} \Big\}$$

And for this example the author states, that

> $$
> \bigcap_{n \in M} A_{n} = \emptyset
> $$

**Problem**

I do not understand why the infinite intersection results in the empty set.

**My thoughts**

- $n$ ranges from $1$ to infinity (never reaching infinity) $\implies$ No $A_{n}$ should be empty, as it should contain at least $\frac{1}{n+1}$
- $A_n$ is the set of real numbers between $0$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ (both exclusive)
- $A_{n} \subsetneq A_{n-1}$ should be true
- So for any $j$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$ *with* $k \leq j$: $A_k$ contains at least $\frac{1}{j+1}$. Therefore the intersection of $A_n$ should contain at least this lowest element.

Example:

$A_1$ from $0$ to $1$

$A_2$ from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$

$A_3$ from $0$ to $\frac{1}{3}$

All of them contain the element $\frac{1}{4}$.

So basically my problem is, that I do not understand where I did make the mistake. Since my thoughts conflict with the statement, that the infinite intersection equals the empty set. Because in my imagination it contains at least one element which goes towards 0 but never reaches 0.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: You are completely correct so far. What you haven't accounted for is the fact that the intersection is infinite. Every finite collection of $A_n$ will have some common element, as you have shown. But, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac 1n<\varepsilon$ by the Archimedean principle, and thus, $\varepsilon\notin A_n$, and so $\varepsilon\notin \bigcap A_n$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, this shows that no positive real is an element of the intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose there was at least one number $x$ in the **infinite** intersection
$$
x \in \bigcap_{n \in M}A_n
$$
by the Archimedean property of real numbers, there is some natural number $N$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{N} < x
$$
and so ${x \notin A_N}$. Meaning we are forced to conclude
$$
x \notin \bigcap_{n \in M}A_n
$$
$x$ was arbitrary. This argument shows that the **infinite** intersection could not possibly have any elements inside, and so
$$
\bigcap_{n \in M}A_n = \emptyset
$$

**TL;DR**: for every number you believe is in the intersection, you can find some $A_N$ such that this number is not in $A_N$. Hence the intersection must be empty.

---

**EDIT**: maybe another way to think about it is this. In the above answer, I gave you a proof that the infinite intersection must be empty, and in the comments I tried to sort of "play to your intuition". Instead, let's look at how we might go about defining some of these things. Expressions such as
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
(which is the same as in your question) don't have any "self-evident" answer. We are required to expand upon what we mean by this sort of expression in order to try and conclude a "reasonable" answer, just like with infinite sums, where we are required to define limits and things to try to make sense of it. If we take everything we know about real numbers as "given" (including, as my proof above uses, the Archimedean property) - and expand the infinite intersection as meaning "any element in the above intersection must belong to **each** set in the intersection", then the proof I did is correct, and the intersection is empty. Since as we said, for any number $x$, we can always find a set ${\left(0,\frac{1}{N}\right)}$ in the intersection such that $x$ is not in this set, and so couldn't be in the intersection.

If the answer was non-empty, it would be a contradiction to my assumptions. Meaning ${(1)}$ what we know about the behaviour of real numbers is broken, or ${(2)}$ I expanded what we meant by the infinite intersection incorrectly. And I don't think there is anything wrong with either assumption. Of course, you could disagree with me, and use alternative definitions - and then you could arrive at different answers. But if you follow the assumptions I made, the only logically sound result is ${\emptyset}$. You could override this if you like, and say "the result is non-empty, there is some number in there" - but then things become inconsistent, since we would start contradicting ourselves.

I think should also help explain your confusion in the comments, as you say

> I can find ${A_N}$ so that ${x_1 \notin A_N}$, but I can also find ${x_2 \in A_N}$. Why is one stronger than the other?

and the answer is because the latter is not how we define an infinite intersection. Not only that, but I don't think this would really be helpful at all in trying to define what we are trying to represent when we say ${\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)}$. Sure, ${x_2}$ is in ${A_N}$ - but **intuitively** we can then find a set for a bigger ${N'>N}$ so that ${x_2}$ is once again not there. So that would not be a helpful definition.

Also, I want to further clarify my example in the comments of
$$
1 + 2 + 3 + \dots
$$
I am definitely **not** saying infinity is a number when I say "we would call the result of this ${\infty}$" <- infinity is not a number, and in the comment I do further state "this is not a positive integer". The **ONLY** point I was trying to make with this example is that if we follow our definition of the infinite sum, and try ${1 + 2 + 3 + \dots}$ - we end up with something that couldn't possibly be a number. In the same way - we followed our definition of an infinite intersection of a bunch of sets that were subsets of eachother, and ended up with something that was **not** one of the sets (none of the ${A_N}$ are ${\emptyset}$). Perhaps this example was not helpful and could add more confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It helped me for sure. There is just one last thing that kind of bugs me: I do understand, that I can find an $A_{N}$ for any $x_{1}$, s.t. $x_{1}$ is not in $A_{N}$. But on the other hand I can find a $x_{2}$ that is in $A_{N}$. Why is one of those "stronger" than the other? Sorry, if this is a stupid question. I just don't feel like I really understood it so far, even though you have answered my original question.

Comment: @Chris No problem! And you are absolutely correct - I think you are confusing the statement ${\bigcap_{n \in M}A_n=\emptyset}$ with saying that one of the ${A_n}$ must be ${=\emptyset}$ - as you pointed out, this is not true. All ${A_n}$ are indeed non-empty. We are saying that if you apply this "intersection operation" to all the ${A_n}$ - the result is ${\emptyset}$ for the reasoning we pointed out. It's the interaction between infinitely many of ${A_n}$ via intersection that causes the result to be ${\emptyset}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Chris perhaps another analogy that could help: the sum of any two positive integers is a positive integer. ${1+1=2}$, ${2+5=7}$, etc. However, does that mean the **infinite** sum ${1+2+3+4+\dots}$ is a positive integer? No. In fact, the result is what we would call ${\infty}$, which is definitely not a positive integer. The situation in your question vs the one I just described are different, but it's similar in the sense that for any finite intersection, such as ${A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3}$, the result is one of those objects (in that case, it's ${A_3}$). This doesn't hold for infinitely many

Comment: To your first reply: No, I still think that e.g. $\frac{1}{n+1}$ should be in every $A_{j}$ with $j < n$ and therefore in their intersection. In my imagination you have something like $\frac{1}{\infty - 1}$ that's part of every $A_{n}$, even though there is no $\infty - 1$. To your second reply: I guess I just have to accept that it is this way. At least I am way closer to understanding it, since you have explained the possibility to find the $A_{N}$. Thanks a lot for your effort, it is really kind of you. I will try to read into the topic of infinity ;)

Comment: And thanks for the analogy, it showed me that I do have a wrong concept of infinity. I always thought it is more like a concept than an actual value. Which lead to the point, that I thought the sum would be a positive integer that diverges to infinity.

Comment: @Chris no worries, once I find some time I'll edit my answer to add some more details. But yes - perhaps a large portion of the confusion lies with the concept of infinity then?

Comment: @Chris added a little more

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but $A_5$ doesn't contain $\frac14$.  For any $x>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $x>\frac1N$.  Then for $n>N$, $x\notin A_n$.  Thus, there is no number in *all* of the $A_n$.

Comment: Thanks, for your explanation. If I could upvote, I would upvote your answer as well. I do understand your point, but there are two things that conflict for me. First: For any $N$ there is an $t$, such that $\frac{1}{t} \in A_{j}$ with $j \le N$. And at this point I don't understand why your statement is "stronger". Second: $A_{n} \subset A_{n-1}$ and the fact that no $A_{j}$ is empty makes me still think the elements in the $A_{n}$ with the highest n should be in all others with lower n. I am sure you guys are right, I don't doubt that. I just try to understand why.

Comment: But as I have said to Riemann'sPointyNose: I will read into the topic of infinity as this seems to be the point where I screw it up. I just did not want to leave you hanging, as you have given advice to me, which is very nice.

Comment: You keep thinking that if $x\in \bigcap_{j=1}^nA_j$ then it's in the intersection all the $A_j$ and this just isn't true.  It's got to be in very single one of the $A_j$.  Say $x=\frac1{1000}$.  Then $x\in A_1$, $x\in A_2,\dots x\in x_{999}$ but $x\notin A_{1000}$, $x\notin A_{1001}\dots$

Comment: What do you mean by "above"?  Can you give me an $x$ that is in $A_{10}, A_{11}, A_{12}, \dots$?  No, because there isn't one.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment. I did not want to bother you with it. I think I may have understood it because of Riemanns edit. Thanks for your input.